# CocoaPods 'pod trunk push' Error Finding File

Tags: cocoapods, podspec

I am trying to publish my library, and when I run: `pod lib lint`
I get `SwiftUIHelper passed validation.`

but when I do `pod trunk push` I get some errors:

```
 -> SwiftUIHelper (0.0.1)
    - WARN  | [iOS] license: Unable to find a license file
    - ERROR | [iOS] xcodebuild: Returned an unsuccessful exit code. You can use `--verbose` for more information.
    - NOTE  | xcodebuild:  note: Using codesigning identity override: -
    - NOTE  | [iOS] xcodebuild:  note: Building targets in dependency order
    - NOTE  | [iOS] xcodebuild:  note: Target dependency graph (3 targets)
    - ERROR | xcodebuild:  SwiftUIHelper/SwiftHelper/Features.swift:24:13: error: cannot find 'ButtonListView' in scope
```

The file `Features` doesn't exist anywhere in my project. I've tried deleting derived data and cleaning build folder but the errors persist. This is my `.podspec` file:

```
Pod::Spec.new do |spec|

  spec.name         = "SwiftUIHelper"
  spec.version      = "0.0.1"
  spec.summary      = "A pod with Swift & SwiftUI Helpers"

  spec.description  = <<-DESC
This CocoaPods library helps you do SwiftUI things.
                   DESC

  spec.homepage     = "https://github.com/***/SwiftUIHelper"
  spec.license      = { :type => "MIT", :file => "LICENSE" }
  spec.author       = { "***" => "***" }

  spec.ios.deployment_target = "16.0"
  spec.swift_version = "5.0"

  spec.source        = { :git => "https://github.com/***/SwiftUIHelper.git", :tag => "#{spec.version}" }
  spec.source_files  = "SwiftHelper/*.{h,m,swift}"

end
```

Comment: "The file Features doesn't exist anywhere in my project." — in project as in `Xcode Project` or in your file system?

Answer (score 1):

`pod trunk push` uses the version of the repo on GitHub specified by the tag in the podspec.

Does version `0.0.1` include `SwiftUIHelper/SwiftHelper/Features.swift`